# Chrome Web Store In-App Payments: Errors getting SKUs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to get the SKUs available for a freemium Chrome Extension I'm developing.

I'm following all of the documentation here: 
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap

...and I'm using the provided buy.js file, but it doesn't seem to work and the returned error messages are useless: "INVALID_RESPONSE_ERROR"

My code:

```
google.payments.inapp.getSkuDetails({
  parameters: {env: 'prod'},
  success: (r) => {
    console.log(r);
  },
  failure: (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  },
});
```

Thoughts:
- Am I missing some permission in my manifest? I don't see any mention that it needs any additional ones.

- Other StackOverflow questions have mentioned needing to proxy due to region issues. I'm in the states, shouldn't be an issue.
- I've tried the above from both an options page and a popup - does it need to happen in a background page?

I'm pretty baffled. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

---

**Updates:**

- The above works when released (in prod), but not locally
- In prod you cannot buy your own thing (heads-up). It'll give you some stupid, meaningless error, but won't tell you that.
- Still can't get this to work locally which means I have to test in prod.

Comment: FWIW: I don't seem to be having this issue when I actually submit the app. It's only on locally loaded extensions.

Comment: Have you completed the 4-step setup in [In-App Payments with Payments Merchant Account and the Chrome Web Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap#testing)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Unrelated, but also worth mentioning: You cannot buy your own product. This tripped me up for a bit when testing in prod.

Comment: If you can't buy your own product, create your own test users and test-buy the product

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Honestly - no. I ended up just testing with another account.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to work locally, you must set the 'key' in your manifest.json file. When you reload it, it will show the same ID as the loaded extension from production.

[Here are instructions on how to get the relevant key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key)

Answer (score 1):

If you debugging your extension in unpacked mode, you may need to set production "key" in your manifest.